# Surround list view by upper and lower elements

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, android-relativelayout

The height of the list view should be the white space in the picture without the height of the elements at the bottom. The list view reaches the bottom at the moment but should not. So basically the list view should be surrounded by the upper elements and the lower elements. How can I achieve this goal?

[image: Rendered XML]

The XML is at the moment the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/groupchat_tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/groupchat_bt_edit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/groupchat_bt_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="bearbeiten"
    android:onClick="editButtonOnClick" />

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/groupchat_lv_conversation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/groupchat_bt_edit"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/groupchat_et_message"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/groupchat_bt_send" />

<Button 
    android:id="@+id/groupchat_bt_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="senden"
    android:onClick="sendButtonOnClick" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention  android:layout_above to the ListView:

```
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/groupchat_lv_conversation"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/groupchat_bt_edit"
android:layout_above="@+id/groupchat_et_message"
android:background="#FFFFFF" />
```